# How to send data from a div tag with ajax without the need for a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div as follows:

```
<div id="test-container">
   <div id="test-one">
      <p id="data">Example to send</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to send what's inside the `<p>` `"Example to send"`
As I can send it without the need to use a form, only using ajax, jQuery and PHP

Thanks!

Comment: where the ajax and event handler?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the content of p using this:

```
var content = $("#data").html();
```

Then you can send it using ajax this way:

```
$.post("url_to_some_file.php", content, function(response){
//Here you can get the response from the server
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need an event to get trigger the ajax function first

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   var data = $('.data').html()
   $.ajax({
      url: 'url_to_server',
      data: data,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(result){
         alert(result)
     }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getdata = $("#data").html(); // get the text inside of the p tag

$.post("yourphpfile.php", {data: getdata}).done(function(r) {

    alert("Data sent!"); // show alert box after the query sent

});
```

to get the data via PHP

```
<?php
 $data = $_POST['data'];


?>
```